# QGIS 3.18 Reprojections result in wrong projection - EPSG 32754 instead of 7854

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, ogr2ogr

When I run a QGIS processing tool that includes a new projection, the result is not correctly projected.

Instead of EPSG::7854 (GDA2020 / MGA 54), the data ends up with EPSG::32754 (WGS 84 / UTM 54 South).

So

```
QGIS version: 3.18.3-Zürich
QGIS code revision: 735cc85be9
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.1.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Merge vector layers' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:7854'), 'LAYERS' : ['A:/5. Shared Documents/GIS/Reference data/GBA - Mapinfo Mapping Files/Culverts.TAB','A:/5. Shared Documents/GIS/Reference data/GBA - Mapinfo Mapping Files/Mine Road Culverts.TAB'], 'OUTPUT' : 'M:/ManGoesMapping/Working/Road_Data/Culverts.tab' }

Using specified destination CRS EPSG:7854
Setting output type to Point
Chainage field in layer Mine Road Culverts has different data type than the destination layer (Integer instead of String). Chainage field will be converted to string type.
Y field in layer Mine Road Culverts has different data type than the destination layer (String instead of Real). Y field will be converted to string type.
Packaging layer 1/2: Culverts
Packaging layer 2/2: Mine Road Culverts
Execution completed in 0.20 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'M:/ManGoesMapping/Working/Road_Data/Culverts.tab'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Merge vector layers' finished
```

Results in
[image]

If I run ogr2ogr using

```
for %%f in (*.tab) do ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" "%%~dpnf_7854.tab" -t_srs EPSG:7854 "%%f" 1>> process.log 2>> error.log
```

The result is correctly projected as in the screen grab from both QGIS and MapInfo
[image]

I am working with MapInfo tab files and haven't noticed the issue with GPKG files.

=== UPDATE ===

If downloading the test data from [https://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/custom/detail.page?fid={550BE3D5-E0A1-43F0-9F1E-0CAB72785771}](https://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/custom/detail.page?fid=%7B550BE3D5-E0A1-43F0-9F1E-0CAB72785771%7D) you can choose the projection as below.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: In QGIS, I create 2 gpkg point-layer in 7854, export them as MapInfo tab files, setting 7854 as destination CRS. Indeed, they are saved in 32754, but still correctly located in the same place as the original files. When I merge these layers, they are still in 32754, but remain located in the same place as the original points. So to me this seems to be a limitation of the MapInfo tab format.

Comment: So to be able reproducing your problem, please describe your workflow and provide sample data.

Comment: Yes they show in the same place but QGIS is reporting them as 32754 -this is the problem. In MapInfo it also shows as 32754.  It should be showing them as 7854. When projected using OGR2OGR they show correctly in MapInfo and QGIS as 7854. An example dataset is `https://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/custom/detail.page?fid={550BE3D5-E0A1-43F0-9F1E-0CAB72785771}` - it can be downloaded in 7854 and say 28354, then use QGIS to convert the 28354 file to 7854 and you (should) see that QGIS will show it as 32754 eventhough it is in the correct place. OGR2OGR converted file will show 7854

Comment: OK, just to understand your problem: coordinate values are the same in both CRS. So simply assigning 7854 to a layer that QGIS shows as 32754 will set the "right" CRS and not change data/projection. Not sure what exactly the problem is?

Comment: I downloaded the file you linked and when I open it, it shows me EPSG:4283 - neither 28354 nor 7854...?

Comment: You need to choose the projection to download the sample in....I am not assigning the projection (forcing the projection). But when I run a tool such as Merge in the example in my question and set the projection for the output as 7854. The tool runs...but when I open the data in QGIS or Mapinfo it shows the projection as 32754. To check if it's an issue in OGR2OGR I ran the conversion using the code in the question and the data then shows correctly in QGIS and Mapinfo as 7854. This only happens with QGIS and TAB files...so I have to keep using OGR2OGR to get the file in the right projection.

Comment: Downloaded the file as MapInfo tab file in 7854, loaded it to QGIS. Shows me layer CRS=7854. Then I run merge vector layers, save output as `TAB` file, destination CRS 7854. You're right, the output layer in QGIS now shows 32754 as layer CRS. So your question is why that happens? Or do you have an issue because of that? Of course, transformation is not 100% exact, I get distances of 1 to 2 meters. But this is normal: 7854 is static (relies on a datum which is plate-fixed), 32754 is dynamic (not plate-fixed).

Comment: So your question is how to avoid this transformation error? Or what the difference between these two CRS is? Or why QGIS automatically switches CRS when saving a `TAB` file? This happens even without processing, just when I try to epxort the file I downloaded from the link you posted from QGIS to a new `TAB` file: setting destination CRS 7854, it still gets saved as 32754. I suppose your question should be clearer about what you want to achieve to get help.

Comment: My main question is how do I get it to project into 7854 and not 32754? All the other questions are relevant but this is the key problem. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: So I would state this clearly in your question to increase chances to get an answer - as of now, I have the impression the question is not clear enough. So processing the data does not play a role here, simple export to `TAB` already causes the problem. Probably a specific incompatibility of QGIS, `TAB`-format in combination with `EPSG:7854`. I use QGIS 3.20, by the way.

Comment: @GeorgeC, this seems like a bug to me. I sugggest you to [create an issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/).